# Searching Text from Oracle database based on text pattern

Tags: java, oracle, spring-mvc

I have requirement where user has search box where he will enter multiple string seperated by spaces.

I have to search in such a way that all strings matching should be shown first and then matching second criteria and atlast least matching.

For example, if the user searches "Device Failed Due", then it must show records matching "Device  Failed Due ",then "Device Failed "or "Failed Due " and other criteria ,atlast single search pattern.

Can anyone sugggest me good and best way of doing using java from oracle DB.

Please kindly Provide me how to  do it in best way

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class Test {
      String input;   //input String
        StringBuffer output;  //Holds the output
        String delimiter = ","; //Delimiter (default comma (,))
        String arrayOfWords[];
        List li=new ArrayList();

        /*
         * Generates combinations by applying the 
         * concept of recursion
         */
        private void nextCombination(int position, int remainder) 
        {     
            output.append(arrayOfWords[position]+this.delimiter);  

            if (remainder == 1) {  
                li.add(output.substring(0,output.length()-1).replace(",",".*"));
//            System.out.println(output.substring(0,output.length()-1));           
            } else {       
              for (int i = position + 1; i + remainder - 1 <= arrayOfWords.length; i++)         
                nextCombination(i, remainder - 1);     
            }

            output.delete(output.indexOf(arrayOfWords[position]),output.length());
        }    

        public void generateCombinations(String input, String delimiter) 
        {     
              output = new StringBuffer();           
              this.input = input;  
              this.delimiter = delimiter;

              /*
               * Splitting the words by delimiter and storing in 
               * an array.
               */
              StringTokenizer buf = new StringTokenizer(input,delimiter);

              int lengthOfArray = buf.countTokens();
              arrayOfWords = new String[lengthOfArray];

              int i = 0;

              while(buf.hasMoreTokens())
              {
                 arrayOfWords[i] = buf.nextToken();
                 i++;
              }

              for (int j = 1; j <= lengthOfArray; j++)       
                  for (int k = 0; k + j <= lengthOfArray; k++)
                  {
                      nextCombination(k, j);                     
                  }
        System.out.println(li);
        } 

        public void generateCombinations(String input) 
        {
            generateCombinations(input, this.delimiter);
        }

        /** 
         * @param args 
         */  
        public static void main(String[] args) {  
            new Test().generateCombinations("SR,78,100",",");



        }  
}
```

Then i will generate sequences then i will query db for each record.Plz can i use this code and the query db

Comment: Oracle has a [built-in matching function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_match.htm#CHDEAEGD) which may or may not be useful to you.

Comment: Your requirement is quite fuzzy.